# changing of https port

Tags: java, http, https

Some websites (like Google) force users to use https. My ISP has decreased Internet speed on port 443, so it takes 30 seconds for me to see my search results! Is there any possible way to redirect it to another port!?

I prefer java programming to implement such a redirect. Anyone can help!?

Comment: Sounds like it's time to change ISP. ;-p

Comment: Better to change the country! All ISPs in my country do the same thing! It's a governmental law! Here is Iran...

Comment: This is not a programming question and should be moved to: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using Chrome which automatically redirects you to https://www.google.com.

If you use Firefox and go to http://www.google.com, you'll still be able to use regular HTTP (I just verified that with Firefox 11).

Comment: No, I use Firefox 11, but it forcibly redirects me to https. I think I need some port mapping on a proxy server.

Comment: That's really strange, sounds like you possibly might have a plugin installed in Firefox that affects this behavior. Out of curiosity, I just tried it in IE 7/8 and accessing http://www.google.com works fine with regular HTTP (no forced redirect) in those browsers as well.

Comment: It's OK on IE! Now I tried it... But not on Firefox. I have no plugin or addon to force it!

Comment: Well, I am running Firefox 11 on Ubuntu, maybe that's the reason for the difference.